# Particionar Base de dato mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Mi pregunta va entorno al siguiente problema.

He creado una base de datos y después de trabajar unos cuantos años en ella la misma se ha vuelto algo grande y por tanto las busquedas en la misma se estan haciendo ineficientes.

My base de dato consiste en unas 35 tablas. No obstante hay 4 o 5 tablas que contienen la mayoria del peso de la bd.

Ahora mismo lo que estoy haciendo es traspasar todos los datos año por año a una base de datos individua y con esto he conseguido que el tiempo de ejecución de las consultar disminuya.

Mi pregunta es ¿es esta la mejor manera de hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Cómo vas a realizar búsquedas dependiendo del año? ¿Y si esas búsquedas involucran 2 o más años? Probablemente solo necesitas optimizar y agregar índices para los campos usados en búsquedas.

Comment: En mi caso las busquedas estan acotadas al año en curso.